# How can I save my data from sql database?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Consider that I have 3 tables (`Order`, `OrderDetials` and `Products`) and each these entities has attributes and I have saved some data in those tables. Now I want to save all those data and keep them somewhere else. Then change some value of those attributes or start a new work with them.

How can I do that can I put those useless data on the CD?

Comment: How large is your database?  Is a full database backup not an option here?

Answer (score 0):

Use "BACKUP" command.

BACKUP DATABASE 'YourDatabase' TO DISK = '~/backup/YourDatabase.BAK'

For more details see.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

Comment: also it means that when I back up those data then I can do what ever I want to the new data with out changing those last data that I have back up them ,is it correct?

Comment: Yes. Correct. When ever you want want old data , just restore from backup.